# Testing for an invalid windows handle: should I compare with 'NULL', '0' or even 'nullptr'?

Tags: c++, windows, null, handles

I'm coming from a background whereby pointers should generally be compared with 'NULL' and integers with '0'.

Since I didn't perceive Windows handles to be 'pointers' in the pure sense (being 'handles'), I'd got into the habit of comparing them with 0 rather than 'NULL'.

Clearly they're implemented internally as pointers nowadays, but I personally consider that to be merely for acquiring some type-safety rather than because they are intrinsically pointers.

Anyway, I just noticed that the help for CreateIC which returns an HDC states that if the function fails then it returns 'NULL'.

Now I'm confused - and am wondering what other people reckon - is it more correct to consider a Windows handle to be a pointer (and therefore check it against 'NULL' or 'nullptr' for modern compilers) or should it be considered to be an integer?

Comment: Handles aren't pointers, but indexes to a table. Consult MSDN for return values. And anyway, why `if (x){..` isn't good?

Comment: Thanks for this one - call me old-fashioned, but I normally reserve the 'if (x)' notation for expressions that evaluate to 'bool' results.  I don't know whether this is good or bad practice, but it's what I'm used to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compare it against the documented error return value. That means that you should compare it against `INVALID_HANDLE`, 0, -1, non-zero, or `<=32` (I'm not kidding with the last one, see ShellExecute).

Comment: Thanks for that answer - I guess you're right, there's not a lot of consistency and I should just do what the MSDN tells me.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: the `HANDLE` type is declared in winnt.h as

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
```

Hence, technically it is a pointer.

However, I would just use whatever is documented; if the documentation states that `NULL` is returned, I use exactly that unless evidence shows that the documentation is incorrect.

I don't even think about pointers vs. integers. `NULL` is just an opaque value (in this situation) and `HANDLE` is an opaque type to me and I don't bother looking up what it is `#define`'d to.

Answer (score 1):

I think `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is usually the proper 'invalid' value for windows handles...and that evaluates to `-1`.

Comment: Thats not always true.  It depends on what API you are calling ... which is a HUGE pain :(

Comment: If you do: `HWND hwnd = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` you get a compile time error.  Which seems odd to me.